# Rails3 + Datamapper - concurrent database connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

Is it possible to use concurrent databases in one rails application?
With AR I can use establish_connection method inside a model. Is it possible with datamapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an analogous feature in `Datamapper`. This snippet from this [cheatsheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/datamapper/) shows how.

```
DataMapper.setup(:colors_db,  "sqlite3:path/to/colors.db")
class Color
   include DataMapper::Resource

   def self.default_repository_name
     :colors_db
   end

   property :name, String
end
```

As you can also see there the `:repository` argument also changes the source database for many of the DM commands.